# pptpd server on Ubuntu - Netflix not working

Tags: netflix, pptp, pptpd

I just setup a pptpd server on ubuntu 14 and for some reason, netflix wont connect, every other website connects.

I have no idea where should I start to debug it... already disabled ufw and it still wont work... any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed, everything was OK on server side, had to change MTU on windows to get it working.

Typed in CMD ( as admin ):

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces
```

then:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "INTERFACE" mtu=1300 store=persistent
```

where **INTERFACE** is the name of the network adapter on the VPN connection.

source: http://www.techkhoji.com/some-websites-not-loading-in-vpn-problem-fix/